# Python - Coin flip streaks

Tags: python

The objective is to write python code to:

(1) Simulate 10,000 coin flips and record the Heads(H) and Tails(T) values in a list. I've named it expList in the following code.
(2) Calculate the number of streaks wherein 6 Heads or 6 Tails come consecutively, and then calculating the percentage of streaks over total flips.

**Is there any error in the following code:**

```
import random

numberOfStreaks = 0
expList = []

for expNumber in range(10000):
    if random.randint(0,1)==0:
        expList.append('H')
    else:
        expList.append('T')

for i in range(len(expList)-5):
    if expList[i] == 'T' and expList[(i+1)]=='T' and expList[(i+2)]=='T' and expList[(i+3)]=='T' and expList[(i+4)]=='T' and expList[(i+5)]=='T':
        numberOfStreaks+=1
    elif expList[i] == 'H' and expList[(i+1)]=='H' and expList[(i+2)]=='H' and expList[(i+3)]=='H' and expList[(i+4)]=='H' and expList[(i+5)]=='H':
        numberOfStreaks+=1

print(numberOfStreaks)
print(f'Chances of streak : {numberOfStreaks*100/10000}')
```

I'm getting really varied probability percentages, when I try different number of flips (say 100000 or 1000, instead of 10,000)

Comment: Please retake the intro tour, especially [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There's no such a thing like random in computer. It just some equations use some numbers from cpu or ram or somewhere around and produce a somewhat distributed value. It perfectly normal that those value will be biased.

Comment: Hi @Prune have updated the post. Hope it makes more sense and is easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: You can likely just use pure math to solve this problem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11415/chance-on-throwing-a-six-with-6-dice.

Comment: Maybe `numpy.random` works better? Maybe instead of random and int, random a float then multiply by a number and then cast to int might give more distribute? But again, they're psuedo random at the end of the day.

Comment: You're still *asking* whether there is an error in your code.  Until you can demonstrate an error, you do not have a Stack Overflow problem.  You provided no output to support your worries.  Again, please complete the MRE.

Comment: Hi @Prune -- I've mentioned my concern at the end of the question, after the code: when I run the code with different number of flips, I'm getting widely different probabilities. To my understanding, that shouldn't be the case if the code is correct.

Comment: @Ajith No, like I already said above. You can just run the same number multiple times and get all different result. Even if your code is correct.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I'm actually trying to solve this practice project from : [Automating the boring stuff with python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter4/)

In that it says it can be solved mathematically as well, which implies it is a more or less fixed percentage.

Comment: You mentioned your concern, a tentative conclusion.  You did not give us the data you have and your method of reaching that concern.  "really varied" is not a problem specification.

Comment: I don't see the word "pseudo random" mentioned even once there, even though it's very important thing. I'd suggest you search for "pseudo random" and "true random" more from somewhere else. I can only say that unless you have a real random generator machine, you can't make any random in computer.

Comment: And "very varied" is what it should be for randomization.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's difficult to follow what's going on. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: You should get equal number of 1 and 0, both around 5000 for 10000 toss, but it doesn't mean consecutive result should be the same. They are different.

Comment: If you get a predictable consecutive result from coin toss, say dice toss in casino, you should suspect that it's not random instead.

Comment: @AjithRajan, firstly when you say "is there an error in the code", I think what you mean Is "is there a mistake" in the code. You say that changing the " number of flips". This is currently an abstract concept since there is no variable for it. I strongly suspect you are changing  the number of flips here `for expNumber in range(10000)` and not here: `{numberOfStreaks*100/10000}'`. make a  variable called `n_flips` and use it in place of both `10000` values to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code contains an error.
Consider an example when 7 heads or 7 tails occur in a row. As per your code, this condition will be counted twice.
['H','H','H','H','H','H','H']
One count will occur for i = 0 another for i = 1 where i represents the index of the list.

Comment: I have posted a question here which also contains the solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239154/coin-flip-streaks You may have a look

Answer (score 0):

My amateur attempt:

```
# Coin Flip Streaks


import random

streaks=0
total=10 # Simplifying calculations
reps=10

for experimentNumber in range(total):
    coin_flips=[] # You must reset the coin_flips list. Your program keeps appending values to ur list without deleting the old ones.

    for j in range(reps):
        coin_flips.append(random.choice(['H','T']))

    repetition=1 # any flip is a streak of at least 1
    for i in range(1,len(coin_flips)):
        if coin_flips[i]== coin_flips[i-1]:
            repetition+=1
        else:
            repetition=1
        if repetition==4:
            streaks+=1
            break

    print(coin_flips) 


total_strks=(reps//4)*total # calculating the total num of strks within all lists 

streaks_per=100*streaks/total_strks # calculating the percent of strks

print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (streaks_per))
print(f'{streaks} of {total_strks}') # In order to test the streaks' counter
```

Let me know, if I missed anything.